# Implementation of the Rebus DryIoc Container Adapter

Tags: rebus, dryioc

This question is targeted to Rebus inventor. If I wanted to make DryIoc as one of built-in Rebus Container Adapter, do I need to customize certain DryIoc source code?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand the question? Are you thinking about making DryIoc part of Rebus.dll?

Comment: Hi mookid. I am just started learning rebus 2. In my opinion, it is a very well coded framework. I wanted to implement rebus 2 in my asp.net web Api 2. My Api will have many functions that will call external Apis. I jumped into [https://github.com/rebus-org/Rebus/tree/master/Rebus.LightInject](https://github.com/rebus-org/Rebus/tree/master/Rebus.LightInject) and I wonder how could I make the same with [DryIoc](https://bitbucket.org/dadhi/dryioc). Thanks for your attention.

Comment: Here the Rebus.DryIoc https://github.com/rebus-org/Rebus/tree/master/Rebus.DryIoc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hello (I am DryIoc maintainer),

I have contributed to [Rebus.DryIoc](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Rebus.DryIoc/) with [DryIoc 2.0.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DryIoc.dll) integration. The package is already available.

Comment: Thanks a lot dadhi. I have visited the repo. Really cool. I will test with my solution will update you with any success or issue.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you take a look at one of the existing container adapters, e.g. the one for Autofac.

Each container adapter project has an [implementation project](https://github.com/rebus-org/Rebus/tree/master/Rebus.Autofac) and a [corresponding test project](https://github.com/rebus-org/Rebus/tree/master/Rebus.Autofac.Tests), which mostly consists of a test fixture that inherits all the contract tests.

If a container adapter has specific matters involving uncertainty, the test project can take care of verifying these things too.

If you submit a pull request with the code, I will be happy to make sure that it's released on NuGet.org :)

Comment: Thanks a lot mookid. What you have done is awesome. The creator of DryIoc has just done it for rebus 2.